# How to check if specific attribute is present in all the child nodes in XML?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

How to check if specific attribute is present in all the child nodes in XML ? For example i want to check if there exists a ws:PriorValue in all the child nodes of ws:Status ?

```
<ws:Status>
<ws:Staffing_Event ws:PriorValue="">LOA</ws:Staffing_Event>
<ws:Staffing_Event_Date ws:PriorValue="">2020-05-01</ws:Staffing_Event_Date>
<ws:Employee_Status ws:PriorValue="Active">OnLeave</ws:Employee_Status>
<ws:Active ws:PriorValue="true">false</ws:Active>
<ws:Hire_Date>2000-01-01</ws:Hire_Date>
</ws:Status>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<xsl:template match="ws:Status">
    <test>
        <xsl:if test="*[not(@ws:PriorValue)]">Not all child elements have a PriorValue attribute</xsl:if>
    </test>
</xsl:template>
```